# Does VS test explorer support formatted error messages

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, test-explorer

I make a test adapter for a custom test framework used in our company to be used in Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer. Our test framework formats error messages of failed unit tests with HTML tags (different fonts and colors, lists, etc.) But VS Test Explorer seems to not support it and shows those tags as plain text it Test Details Summary window.

Does VS Test Explorer support any kind of error message formatting?

Comment: Hi Mykola, which api do you use to extension the test explorer window?  Test-related api [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1830) or APIs from [VS SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2019)?

Comment: I didn't know about those APIs, will check them out. For test adapter I use [vstest](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest), in particular NuGet [Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel) (version 15.9.0 for same dlls which are used by VS 2019), and implement ITestDiscoverer and ITestExecutor.